# mongodb compass - white screen

Tags: drivers, mongodb

I got this error message after installing mongodb compass and running it from the command line. The application launches and the window turns white a few seconds later.

```
gilles@X1c:~/Projets/feamzy$ mongodb-compass 
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[108930:0928/165527.343247:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[108930:0928/165605.708497:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
[108930:0928/165608.832343:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!
```

PC configuration:

[image: PC configuration]

I verified my GPU driver:

```
gilles@X1c:~/Projets/feamzy$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.14 (libva 2.12.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.3.1 ()
```

I solved the first error => `export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=iHD`
On the other hand, the second persists and the application still crashes.

While waiting for a solution I installed 1.39 instead of 1.40. It seems to work although there are still the same error messages.

Answer (score 3):

The error also occurred with version `1.40.2`, so I checked the version on my other computer and resolved it using these 3 commands, forcing the installation to version `1.39.3`:

1. `wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.39.3_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.39.3_amd64.deb`
3. `mongodb-compass`